# How to detect QR code corner markers (only) using OpenCV + Python?

Tags: python, opencv, qr-code

I would like to detect the QR code corner markers using OpenCV. I have used the QR code markers in the corners of a data table which will be printed. The algorithm must handle distortions.

[image]

[image]

There is a great post on "[Python - Detect a QR code from an image and crop using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384780/1594557)" but it handles the table as a unit, not identifying corner markers.

[image]

I have also tried [Harris corner detection and Shi-Tomasi corner detection](https://www.programmersought.com/article/80084716232/#_1) but this only gets me so far.

[image]

I would like to be able to extract the co-ordinates of the 4 corners of the marker:

[image]

Note: I want to **avoid image template matching** because it is computationally inefficient.

Comment: This can be solved using dlib shape predictor. You will need to generate random dataset with tables and corner markers to feed it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion @Hihikomori. To clarify: I am looking for an analytical approach using points and edges, not a probabilistic approach when model training is required.

Comment: Apply cv2.Laplacian, with kernel=15 and uint8 type, and then cv2.findContours. Each corner marker will give several contours, I believe, at least 3, that have the same center, and can be scaled to each other, and can be approximated with quad.

Comment: have you got any updates on this, I am also looking for similar problem